# Chart.js line chart not showing in Google Chrome canvas(only in Microsoft Edge)

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

Using Chart.js library. Programm works only in the Microsoft Edge browser. The other browsers just give a black canvas
Chart.js version 2.9.3 "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.js"

**ERRORS:**
data1.js:30 Fetch API cannot load file:///C:/Users/avtor/Documents/Job/stock_bot/myChart/myChart1/intraday_5min_MSFT.csv. URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request.

getData @ data1.js:30
data1.js:30 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
at getData (data1.js:30)
at getChart1 (data1.js:5)
at data1.js:3

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
        <html>
        <link rel="stylesheet" 
         href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.js" ></script>
        <head>
           <title>Money Thingy</title>
        </head>
        <body>

      <canvas id="myChart" style='height: 100;width: 800;background:#282c34;z-index: -50;'></canvas>

      <script src="data1.js">  </script>

  </body>
   </html>
```

The js part ( reading data from CSV file )

```
const xLabels=[];
const yTemps =[];
getChart1();
async function getChart1(){
await getData();
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');


const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
type: 'line',
data: {
    labels: xLabels,
    datasets: [{
        label: 'MSFT',
        data: yTemps,
        backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)'
        ],
        borderColor: [
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)'
        ],
        borderWidth: 1

    }]
}

 });
}
    async function getData() {
      const response = await fetch ('intraday_5min_MSFT.csv');
      const data = await response.text();
      const table = data.split('\n').slice (1);
      table.forEach(row => {
        const columns= row.split(',');
        const time =columns[0];
        xLabels.push(time);
        const volume = columns[4];
        yTemps.push (volume);
        console.log(time,volume);

      });
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to work fetch properly, you need to serve your file from an HTTP server. In the error, I can see the file is fetching directly from the file manager which won't work with fetch API.

So you can solve this by two methods. 
Install `apache server` and serve the file from the `localhost.` Install apache and move the files to `\var\www\html` in Linux and `/xampp/htdocs/` in windows.

Or you can install a `live server` extension in your IDE so that the file will be loaded from a server.